# In a series DC circuit, how can one show that the current at each point is same mathematically?

Tags: electric-circuits, electronics

This question has been asked more than ten times in this site before, but almost all of the links I Found are based on informal intuitive argument.

In this post, I am asking if it is possible to show this must be the case through considering maxwell's equation and the assumptions we take for usual circuit. By the assumptions, I mean things like connecting wires being resistanceless.

Comment: The fundamental assumption is that the connecting wires have no capacitance, so charge can't pile up anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am asking if it is possible to show this must be the case through considering maxwell's equation and the assumptions we take for usual circuit

Yes. The continuity equation can easily be derived from Maxwell’s equations as follows: from Ampere’s law $$\nabla \times \vec H = \vec J + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \vec D$$ then taking the divergence of both sides $$\nabla \cdot \left( \nabla \times \vec H \right) = \nabla \cdot \vec J + \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left( \nabla \cdot \vec D \right)$$ $$0 = \nabla \cdot \vec J + \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left( \nabla \cdot \vec D \right)$$ finally, by Gauss’ law we have $$0 = \nabla \cdot \vec J + \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\rho$$

So from Maxwell’s equations we get the continuity equation. This is always valid whenever Maxwell’s equations are valid, and it represents the conservation of charge.

Then, we apply the lumped element approximation of circuit theory to get $$0 = \Sigma I + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} Q$$ and finally we add the assumption that there is no net charge on any lumped element so $Q=0$ (note, this is the net charge on a lumped element, not the charge on one plate of a capacitor) which finally gives us $$0=\Sigma I$$ This is Kirchoff’s current law, and it implies that the current is the same at each point along a series circuit.

Comment: Could you justify how the current density turned discrete? Also how did charge density change turn into rate of charge change? How is $\partial_t Q$ different from $I$?

Comment: @Buraian that is the standard lumped element model. You get rid of the geometry by integrating over an arbitrary surface defining your “black box” lumped element, and by focusing on a topology of discrete “ports” into the surface, each with a current and voltage shared by some other connected lumped element. $Q$ is the charge in the boundary of the element, the volume integral of $\rho$. $I $ is the current crossing the boundary, the surface integral of $\vec J $

Comment: Interesting, I think I follow everything except the topology part. Could you explain that in a bit more detail or say where I could read more of that?

Answer (score 1):

This concept can be demonstrated by invoking *continuity*, as follows.

We begin by looking at the first circuit element in the series circuit. Current i enters the element and since there are no branches within it, the current exiting the element is identically equal to i.

This same reasoning is then applied to each subsequent circuit element.

For an explicit derivation, see *Kirchhoff's laws".

Comment: Kirchoff's voltage law is fine you can show from Maxwell eqtn. I am interested in how to show the current law and the continuity one particularly

Comment: Continuity is a fundamental empirical law, like F=ma. It is however consistent with Maxwell's equations, so you could "derive" it from that, although it's more fundamental than that. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation

Comment: Just to state this explicitly: Kirchhoff's current law follows directly from the continuity equation (derivable from Maxwell's equations as flevinBombastus points out), which is a statement of *conservation of charge*.